# A task on the *nix command line

Tags: sorting, unix, uniq

There is a file with lines like: host ip page. You need to output 10 IP addresses that are more common than others.

I want to solve a small problem.
Please advise, how do you like this solution?

```
sort list|uniq -c|sort -r|head -n 10
```

For example, I have the source file (list.txt):

```
localhost1 144.12.34.245 page1
localhost2 144.12.34.241 page2
localhost3 144.12.34.242 page3
localhost4 144.12.34.243 page4
localhost4 144.12.34.243 page4
localhost4 144.12.34.243 page4
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
```

The same ip address can have different hosts and pages. They are separated by a single space.

For example:

> (localhost5 144.12.34.244 **page5**, localhost5 144.12.34.244
> **page6**)
>
> (**localhost1** 144.12.34.244 **page5**, **localhost5** 144.12.34.244
> **page6**)
>
> (localhost5 **144.12.34.244** page5, localhost5 **144.12.34.144**
> page5)

After executing the command, I get the result:

```
4 localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
3 localhost4 144.12.34.243 page4
1 localhost3 144.12.34.242 page3
1 localhost2 144.12.34.241 page2
1 localhost1 144.12.34.245 page1
```

Almost perfect.
But I would like to output only a list of ip addresses. Without a host and pages:

```
144.12.34.244
144.12.34.243
144.12.34.242
144.12.34.241
144.12.34.245
```

Comment: Are you asking for code review? That would be the wrong site. Is anything not working as you want it to? Are you having problems?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'm sorry that I didn't prepare the question well. I have made some changes to my question.

Comment: Are you comfortable with `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: @Beta, By the way, yes! We can use any of these utilities! I'll try to experiment with them.

Comment: I suggest `sed '...' list | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | sed '...'`

Comment: `sort` with `-n` option and `cut` afterwards will work, `awk` with `{ ip[$2]++} END {something}` looks better.

Comment: Is it possible to have different `pageX` values for the same combination of host name and IP address? (`localhost5 144.12.34.344 page5`, `localhost5 144.12.34.344 page6`) Can you have different combinations of hostname and IP address, e.g. a host with multiple IP addresses? (`localhost5 144.12.34.344 page5`, `localhost5 144.12.34.144 page5`) If any answer is "yes", please modify your example input to show such cases. Add the expected output matching the input. Can I assume that you want to ignore the hostname and page columns? Are the columns separated by a single space? BTW: IP addr bytes<256

Comment: @Bodo, Yes, that's a good point. I made some edits.

Comment: From your changes it is still not yet clear to me how you want to handle different pages or different host names with the same IP address. I suggest to add such lines to your example input and adapt the corresponding output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to ignore the hostname and page fields and only count the IP addresses, you can use

```
awk '{print $2}'  input |sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|head -10|awk '{print $2}'
```

Example input:

```
localhost1 144.12.34.245 page1
localhost2 144.12.34.241 page2
localhost3 144.12.34.242 page3
localhost4 144.12.34.243 page4
localhost4 144.12.34.243 page4
localhost4 144.12.34.243 page4
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page6
localhost1 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page6
localhost5 144.12.34.244 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.144 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.0 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.1 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.2 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.3 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.4 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.5 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.6 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.7 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.8 page5
localhost5 144.12.34.9 page5
```

Resulting output:

```
144.12.34.244
144.12.34.243
144.12.34.9
144.12.34.8
144.12.34.7
144.12.34.6
144.12.34.5
144.12.34.4
144.12.34.3
144.12.34.245
```

Comment: Yes, indeed! I want to consider only unique ip addresses. The rest can be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for considering my problem in such detail!
I am very pleased!

Comment: @Mardaunt As I already wrote it would be good to extend your example input to show all possible variants. If this answer solves your problem you can accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Yes. Now problems!

Answer (score 1):

You add this after your command:

```
| awk -F " " '{print $3}'
```

This means:

```
-F " "       : separate your data in columns, the separator is a space.
'{print $3}' : this awk script says only to write the third column.
```

Comment: a great addition!